# Fourier font with round parenthesis

Tags: fonts

Observe the non-round shape of the parenthesis using the fourier package `\usepackage{fourier}` . In particular they are not round :

[image] [image]

compare this to lmodern parenthesis which are round in shape
[image] [image]

I'd like to replace the  parenthesis used by the fourier  font with a suitable compatible replacement which has a round shape.

It seems not trivial since I would have to replace every parenthesis shape and not just an individual symbol. I would like the fix to be compatible with usage of e.g. `\bigl` and so forth.

Comment: Does this, https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/14388/14103, help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Imho the cm-delimiters don't look good in combination with fourier, but beside this it is a simple case of redefining the delimiter:

```
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareSymbolFont{cmoperators}   {OT1}{cmr} {m}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFont{cmlargesymbols}{OMX}{cmex}{m}{n}

\usepackage{fourier}

\DeclareMathDelimiter{(}{\mathopen} {cmoperators}{"28}{cmlargesymbols}{"00}
\DeclareMathDelimiter{)}{\mathclose}{cmoperators}{"29}{cmlargesymbols}{"01}

\begin{document}

\[
f(x)  f\bigl( x \bigr) f\Biggl( x \Biggr )
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I was trying to to replace them with the mathdesign style, I cannot seem to locate the appropriate dcl files for math design. I belive it is some  mdsymbols file which I cannot locate but there is also mdlargesymbols?  Perhaps there is a more harmonic font parenthesis that you recommend other than mathdesign. In addition, this does not seem to also replace the text mode parenthesis.

Comment: mathdesign offers various styles and without an minimal example I won't try to guess which one you want. And not, you can't replace text parenthesis this way. You would need a virtual font for this.